# excel conditional formating with multiple date ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have looked for proper formula that would solve my problem but I couldn't find anything. 
I have a table with multiple date ranges and I want to highlight all dates in my calendar between these ranges. I've tried to use formula AND

```
=AND(F5>=$A$6,F5<=$B$6)
```

however the formula highlights only dates between 1st range. I tried to put array ($A6:$A$9 and $B6:$B$9) but it doesn't work.

```
       Column A     Column B
row 6 | 05/01/2018 | 12/01/2018  
row 7 | 03/04/2018 | 16/04/2018  
row 8 | 06/05/2018 | 17/05/2018  
row 9 | 01/11/2018 | 05/11/2018
```

My calendar starts in cell F5 and ends in AP16.

Regards,
Adrian

Comment: Is that a typo in B8?  Should that year be 2018 also?

Comment: yes there is a typo, t was just an example, formulas provided below works perfectly fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your AND's within an OR:

```
=OR(AND(F5>=$A$6,F5<=$B$6),AND(F5>=$A$7,F5<=$B$7), AND(...))
```

or, in a more compact but equivalent form:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((F5>=$A$6:$A$9)*(F5<=$B$6:$B$9))
```

or

```
=OR((F5>=$A$6:$A$9)*(F5<=$B$6:$B$9))
```

Each of the equality arrays returns an array of `1`'s or `0`'s.  Multiplying them together is the equivalent of `AND` and will return a `1` if and only if both values in the same position are `TRUE`.  Adding the arrays (the equivalent of `OR`) will then show if any result is a `1`.

Although Excel 2016 will accept an `OR` in the conditional format formula, I seem to recall that some earlier versions will not, hence I have also supplied the equivalent `SUMPRODUCT` formula.

Answer (score 1):

Or once again you can use countifs

```
=COUNTIFS($A$6:$A$10,"<="&F5,$B$6:$B$10,">="&F5)
```