# Excel - Conditional formatting with multiple date ranges with one criteria

Tags: excel, date, formatting, conditional-statements, range

I have a Excel sheet with two tables like the image bellow,

[image]

I need to do a conditional formatting to highlight the dates, on table A, that are inside the range of the table B, accordingly to the process number.

For example, for the process number 123456 I have two intervales in the table B, so the result should be,

[image]

I want to be able to do this for all the process numbers in the table A that have correspondence in table B.

In table B i can have multiple intervales for one process number, in this example this happens for the process number 123456.

[excel conditional formating with multiple date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096018/excel-conditional-formating-with-multiple-date-ranges)

With the post above I can retrive the data ranges from table B and apply the conditional formatting, but i need to insert the "Process number" criteria, otherwise excel applies the formatting to the entire column.

Can anyone help me?

Note: This is a simplified version of my tables, only to make easy to explain.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

- Select area that should contain the conditional format. In my example start with **B2** to make it the active cell.
- Enter `=COUNTIFS($A$8:$A$10,$A2,$B$8:$B$10,"<="&B2,$C$8:$C$10,">="&B2)>0` into the formula field.

**Explaining the formula**

CountIfs count the number of occurances that match the following criteria. Highlight if there is any, in other words if the result of the formula is **>0**.

**Explaining the params**

- $A$8:$A$10 = Process numbers column (B list)
- $A2 = Process number in current row (A list)
- $B$8:$B$10 = Start date column (B list)
- B2 = reference to **active** cell; "<=" to check whether start date is smaller or equal current date
- $C$8:$C$10 = End date column (B list)
- B2 = reference to **active** cell; ">=" to check whether enddate is greater or equal current date